# What to do with "rude" app store promo codes..?

Tags: app-store

I recently generated promo codes for the iOS app store and at least one contains some combinations of letters that you better not pronounce on TV (to say the least). Is there any way to return or change such codes? I mean, I can't send that code to a reviewer, not even to a friend.

Edit: with "generated" I mean that I used iTunes Connect to get promo codes, i.e. Apple creates them and I just download them as a text file. One of the codes reads xxMFxxxxANAL. No joke! (x=arbitrary character not disclosed here). Not exactly the kind of code you want to send to somebody whom you would like to review your app...

Is there anything I can do about this? For example returning the code and getting a new one? And do you have to check every code Apple gives you by hand? If you want to give a batch to a website to give them out to their users, such a code could slip through easily.

Comment: Have a dictionary list of combinations to force a regeneration, if it matches an item in the dictionary.

Comment: I just ran into this very issue with 6 digit codes from a hand-picked pool of digits and letters. Something like `URFUKT` is so hard to predict and account for with a blacklist...

Answer (score 2):

Remove vowels from your character set?

Comment: Not a bad idea! You'd have to already have a dirty mind to misinterpret something without vowels, I can't even come up with a bad one.

Comment: You can use a subset of the full alphabet that makes bad words less likeley, i.e no vowels, and remove the consonants most commonly in unwanted words. And no numbers that look like letters. After you pick them pay some college kids to spend a few hours trying to embarrass you using only that picked alphabet.

Comment: Well, I don't get it. Is there any way I can influence the promo codes that Apple sends me???

Answer (score 0):

Before returning the generated promo code, check it against a list of words you don't want to send. If it is in that list, regenerate it.

**EDIT**
However, that is really not the best solution. It might serve you well to change how you generate the code.
One possibility: in C# there is a Guid class that generates a guaranteed unique string. You may be able to use a subset of a Guid as your promo code.
Another Possibility: You could alternate letters and numbers.

Comment: Better than nothing, but there's always the ones you don't think of that are look-alikes with alternate characters, especially if numbers are in the mix... EETMEE, etc. (I purposely picked a tame one, but hopefully you see what I mean).

Comment: The only issue is guids are long and difficult to communicate over the phone, or type into a text box. It's worse for the end user in many cases. I think only using a subset would make me paranoid of duplicates, but that can be addressed separately - however there is still the same potential risk, and you cannot change the pool of characters.

Comment: @notkilroy Well, no, your answer (and also the other answer) do not address my problem. My problem is that I get codes from Apple and that Apple apparently doesn't make sure that the codes are "G-rated".